# Can an encrypted PDF incrementally updated

Tags: pdf

I wonder whether it is allowed to incrementally update an encrypted PDF? I have gone through the ISO standard and have no clue about it. Can some PDF experts shed the lights?

It it allows, the trailers will have different /Encrypt entries:

```
xref
0 4
0000000000 65535 f
0000000818 00000 n
0000000868 00000 n
0000004001 00000 n
trailer
<</Size 4/Encrypt 5 0 R>>
startxref

xref
4 5
0000000016 00000 n
0000000515 00000 n
0000000651 00000 n
0000000710 00000 n
0000000396 00000 n
trailer
<</Size 9/Prev 4091/Root 6 0 R/Encrypt 7 0 R>>
```

Comment: *"It it allows, the trailers will have different /Encrypt entries"* - Why?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it will not be a problem since that's how edits are allowed to be made to restricted files.

Since the initial file is secured against changes, then a PDF viewer applies the file open password to allow the desired edits. Here I simply add basic annotation, can be anything, but it is then up to the editing PDF viewer how it rewrites the file. Lighter viewers tend to use incremental writing.

This simple viewer does not re-edit entries simply duplicate them incrementally at the end, for other editor / viewers to detect and use.

[image]

So the Viewer (with password to open file) can use the same encryption. Hence it amends the required entry point (here #4) then appends additional data (here #7 #8 #9)

Here the upper view shows the Blue secured file with a Red appendage (**Incremental** addition in secured file.)

However say we wish to change the password and edit that Increment to better it, the file will need for the new encryption a rewrite.

[image]

Also it is much easier for empowered web viewers like Chromium to totally re-edit the file, rather than use simpler incremental appending.

[image]

Comment: As an aside, there is an error in the PDF you show, the trailer contain an `/Info<<>>` but according to spec the **Info** value _shall be an indirect reference_.

Comment: I think the spec merely wants the Info value to be indirect to make sure that the trailer itself is pretty short. Thus, hardly any processor will be bothered. The **Info** entry in general is optional, so no processor should be bothered either if you simply drop it.